# jQuery Sortable - cancel and revert not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

### Problem ([jsFiddle demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9THR9/))

I'm having some trouble with the `revert` setting when used in conjunction with the `cancel` method in the jQuery sortable. The cancel method, as documented in the [jQuery Sortable documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-cancel) states:

> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it back to how it
>   was before the current sort started. Useful in the stop and receive
>   callback functions.

This works fine in both the `stop` and `receive` callbacks, however if I add a `revert` *duration* to the sortable connected list, it starts to act funny (see [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9THR9/)).

Ideally, upon cancelling, the `revert` could simply not happen, or alternatively in a more ideal world, it would gracefully revert to it's original location. Any ideas how I can get the `revert` and `cancel` to play nice?

### Expected

1. Drag from left list to right list
2. Drop item
3. Item animates to **original** location *- or -* immediately shifts to original location

### Actual

1. Drag from left list to right list
2. Drop item
3. Item animates to **new** location, assuming sortable is successful
4. Item immediately shifts to original location, as sortable was cancelled

### Clarification

The `revert` property moves the item to the location where the item would drop if successful, and then immediately shifts back to the original location due to the `revert` occurring before the `cancel` method. Is there a way to alter the life-cycle so if the `cancel` method is executed, `revert` isn't, and instead the item is immediately return to it's original location?

Comment: Apologies, updated the question for clarity.

Comment: I've been playing around with it on jsfiddle. It seems that the revert option _also_ delays when the beforeStop, stop and receive event functions are called.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/MBTAm/12/

Comment: That's interesting @ReyGonzales, I think I may have to resort to amending the jQuery-ui library itself, or alternatively write my own `revert` animation which executes at the appropriate time if the sortable was successful.

Comment: all those jsfiddle's are deleted, what now? :(

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses, I've updated the links to point to a new jsFiddle which has the same problem. :)

Comment: As of Feb 2014 this bug (IMO) exists. Is this as designed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours for searching for a solution I decided the only way to achieve what I was trying to do was to amend the way in which the jQuery sortable plugin registered the revert time. The aim was to allow for the `revert` property to not only accept a `boolean` or `integer`, but also accept a `function`. This was achieved by hooking into the `prototype` on the `ui.sortable` with quite a lot of ease, and looks something like this.

### jQuery Sortable Hotfix

```
$.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStop = function(event, noPropagation)
{
    if (!event) return;

    // if we are using droppables, inform the manager about the drop
    if ($.ui.ddmanager && !this.options.dropBehaviour)
        $.ui.ddmanager.drop(this, event);

    if (this.options.revert)
    {
        var self = this;
        var cur = self.placeholder.offset();

        // the dur[ation] will not determine how long the revert animation is
        var dur = $.isFunction(this.options.revert) ? this.options.revert.apply(this.element[0], [event, self._uiHash(this)]) : this.options.revert;

        self.reverting = true;

        $(this.helper).animate({
            left: cur.left - this.offset.parent.left - self.margins.left + (this.offsetParent[0] == document.body ? 0 : this.offsetParent[0].scrollLeft),
            top: cur.top - this.offset.parent.top - self.margins.top + (this.offsetParent[0] == document.body ? 0 : this.offsetParent[0].scrollTop)
        }, !isNaN(dur) ? dur : 500, function ()
        {
            self._clear(event);
        });
    } else
    {
        this._clear(event, noPropagation);
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Implementation

```
$('ul').sortable({
    revert: function(ev, ui)
    {
        // do something here?
        return 10;
    }
});
```

Comment: Beautiful in concept. I'll have to test it out.

Comment: I fail to understand what you did. How can one use this hotfix to animate the item to its original position, can you create a fiddle to show it off? Thank you

Comment: @Odys this allows you to alter the revert animation duration by certain conditions, for example, if something bad happens the item reverts to its original position instantly: `return 0;`, else use normal revert animation `return 1000;`. This does not make the item return to original with normal (non instant) animation, though.

Answer (score 5):

i created a demo for you here:

[the jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/jraWM/)

it seems to produce the output you expect.

i changed the receive callback method from this:

```
$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
```

to this:

```
$(ui.sender).sortable( "option", "revert", false );
```

hopefully, this is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chrisvillanueva, sadly though there is a key reason to to why this won't work; the `receive` is only triggered after the revert animation has occurred, meaning that on the first drop, the `revert` is still set to animate. Ideally I need to be able to cancel the revert, if a `cancel` is triggered during a certain event... the question is, which event? :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new event called beforeRevert which should return true or false. If false then the cancel function is called and the item is animated back to its original position. I didn't code this with the helper option in mind, so it would probably need some additional work to support that.

### jQuery Sortable Hotfix with animation

```
var _mouseStop = $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStop;
$.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStop = function(event, noPropagation) {
  var options = this.options;
  var $item = $(this.currentItem);
  var el = this.element[0];
  var ui = this._uiHash(this);
  var current = $item.css(['top', 'left', 'position', 'width', 'height']);
  var cancel = $.isFunction(options.beforeRevert) && !options.beforeRevert.call(el, event, ui);

  if (cancel) {
    this.cancel();
    $item.css(current);
    $item.animate(this.originalPosition, {
      duration: isNaN(options.revert) ? 500 : options.revert,
      always: function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', '');
        $item.css({position: '', top: '', left: '', width: '', height: '', 'z-index': ''});
        if ($.isFunction(options.update)) {
          options.update.call(el, event, ui);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  return !cancel && _mouseStop.call(this, event, noPropagation);
};
```

### Implementation

```
$('ul').sortable({
  revert: true,
  beforeRevert: function(e, ui) {
    return $(ui.item).hasClass('someClass');
  }
});
```

Comment: This throws error `TypeError: b.replace is not a function jquery.js:4:7342`