# Move a drag and dropped DIV back to it's previous location programatically using jQueryUI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using `jQueryUI Sortable` to build a `KanBan` style board.  THe boards will be used to hold **Order records** from a database.  Each bBoard/Column is a "Status" that the Order record is currently in.  So as an order progresses through the assembly line, it can be drag and dropped to a new board/column which will then make an AJAX request to update the order records status database column.

This image should help explain better...

[image]

After you drag and drop an order to a new column/board it shows an alert dialog like this image below.  If you accept it, it will then make the AJAX request to save the new column/board for this order record that was just moved.

If you click **Cancel** then it will not make the AJAX request.  THis means the ordr rcord will technically still be saved as being under it;s previous column.  HOwever in the DOM it will be dropped in it;s new location.

I need to figure out how I can make the order record move back to it;s previous column when a drag and drop is canceled via the alert dialog.

Any ideas how to programmatically move the order record to it;s previous board/column?

[image]

Basic JavaScript code...

```
$(function() {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });

    // Event fired when order cards has been moved to a new column
    $(".column").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui){

      var newStatusColumnName = $(this).data('status-name');

      // Show a confirmation Dialog.
      // Approve = AJAX save new column that order was moved to
      // Cancel = Do not save new value to database and move order
      // back to previous board/column

    });

});
```

---

**Demo JSFidle setup here** http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/wv6fchmv/

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661514/jquery-ui-sortable-restore-position-based-on-some-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
            'Cancel': {
                'class': 'gray',
                'action': function() {

                    // need to move the order card back to its previous status column somehow!
                   $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

                }
            }
```

on the cancel button click

Updated your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wv6fchmv/2/

More here [jQuery Sortable - cancel and revert not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103447/jquery-sortable-cancel-and-revert-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks I had just got it working also with a different method here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/wv6fchmv/3/ however I need to get the value of the new dropped on column which is broken now in my example.  I will check out youre solution now as well thanks

Comment: Great your solution works using my existing code so I have the value for new column still thanks this will work great